# Function as sum of distances over a connected, compact metric space

Tags: mg.metric-geometry

If $X$ is a connected, compact metric space with distance function $d : X^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^+$, is it true that there exists a positive real number $a$, dependent on $X$ and $d$, such that for any $n$ and for any $x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_n \in X$, there exists $y$ such that $$\frac{1}{n}\left(d(x_1,y) + d(x_2,y) + \cdots + d(x_n,y)\right) = a?$$

Motivation: trivial when $X$ is the boundary of a circle, a tricky contest problem when $X$ is the boundary of a square (these examples all use Euclidean distance)

Comment: the "boundary of a circle"???

Answer (score 6):

It's a classic theorem of O. Gross from 1964. The number $a$ is also unique for a given space $(X,d)$.

There is an exposition at [Cleary and Morris - Numbers for shapes](https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/upload_library/22/Ford/Cleary-Morris-Yost260-275.pdf).

The original paper is:
O. Gross, "The rendezvous value of a metric space", *Advances in Game Theory, Ann. of Math. Studies no. 52*, Princeton, 1964, 49–53.

Answer (score 5):

The answer is "yes".

Arguing by contradiction assume there is no such number.
By 1-dimensional [Helly's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helly%27s_theorem), there is a pair of point-arrays $\{x_1,\dotsc,x_n\}$ and $\{y_1,\dotsc,y_m\}$
such that for their average distance functions $f(z)=\tfrac1n\cdot\sum_i\lvert x_i-z\rvert$ and $h(z)=\tfrac1m\cdot\sum_j\lvert y_j-z\rvert$, we have
$$f(p)>h(q)$$
for any two points $p$, $q$.

Note that
$$\tfrac1m\cdot\sum_if(y_i)=\tfrac1{m\cdot n}\cdot\sum_{i,j}\lvert x_i-y_j\rvert=\tfrac1n\cdot\sum_ih(x_i),$$
a contradiction.

Comment: Why is it enough to consider only two sets $X$ and $Y$? By compactness it is possible to choose a finite number, but how do you reduce it to two?

Comment: @erz it is 1-dimesional Helly's theorem.